# Nodejs always print an 'a' at starting up

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

My Nodejs has a very strange problem.
While running at window cmd, all the 'node' and 'npm' command will first print an 'a' before the expected output. Shown below: [image: problem preview]

How can I fix it?

**problem remains after re-installing T_T**

Comment: you can try re-installing node

Comment: problem remains after re-installing T_T

Comment: does this happen when you running inside node terminal too ? Like console.log("test").

Comment: no, inside the node terminal(even inside `node -p`), everything seem normal

Comment: the 'a' only appear once. `node main.js`>`atesttest`

`main.js: console.log('test');console.log('test');`

Comment: My first guess would be a shell alias or macro. E.g. on *nix I could do `alias node='echo -n a && node'` to achieve your output with `node -v` in the future.

Comment: does window have similar command as alias?

Comment: But i dont install any shell alias or macro.